# Looking for a font which has a similar A bar height and R counter height

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, sans-serif

I am trying to make a sans (perhabs slab) serif version of the upper part of the emblem below, which is a join of letters A and R:

[image]

Can anyone recommend a font suitable for this? With a similar height of A-bar and finish of R counter, while also the letter A would need to have a little more rounded (prolonged) stroke instead of a diagonal one.

Comment: That doesn't look like a font. It appears to have been hand drawn.

Comment: yes, the part of the emblem is hand drawn, I'd like to replace it with a sans-serif characters A and R joined together in half of the width of the letter A and I am looking for a relevant font.

Comment: OK, added an answer that might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I feel these are not letter forms from an actual font - they look pretty rough and I'd suggest it is a hand drawn logotype.

If you want to do something similar, but with a sans serif font, you could use almost any one, then alter the outlines in vector image editing software.

For example, I made this in the free software Inkscape, using just Arial.

[image]